# ASP MVC display matrix (array[,]) in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello I have asp mvc view page,

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Drawing.Color[,]>" %>
```

how I can make a loop by this model and show all elements ?

I not using Razor :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 2 nested loops, one for the rows and one for the columns of the matrix:

```
<table>
    <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.GetLength(0); i++) { %>
        <tr>
            <% for (int j = 0; j < Model.GetLength(1); j++) { %>
                <td>
                    <%= Model[i, j] %>
                </td>            
            <% } %>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```